# How to run both items in scrapy function?

Tags: python, scrapy

Whenever I  use the link of `captions and transcription` in `start_urls` variable, it gives me the price of `caption` in both captions and transcription variable and again give me the price of `transcription` in both variables. Why and how to solve this issue?

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions',
                  'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = FetchingItem()
        Transcription_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()
        Caption_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()

        items['Transcription_price'] = Transcription_price
        items['Caption_price'] = Caption_price
        yield items
```

Comment: you use the same css selector in both `css()` so you have to get the same values.

Comment: if you need  different result for different urls then you have to use different parser for every url. OR you have to use some `if/else` to recognize url and fill different field in `item`

Comment: css selector are same but they are in different pages. I know that.

Comment: if start_urls['hi']:
   items['Transcription_price'] = Transcription_price. It's not working

Comment: (1) `start_urls` is not local variable but class variable and you have to use `self.start_urls`. (2) `self.start_urls` is list, not dictionary so you can't use `['hi']`. (3) `self.start_urls` doesn't have information which url is parsed in `parser()`  - better see `print(response.url)`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need another structure of class, sequential:

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = FetchingItem()
        items['Caption_price'] = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()
        yield Request('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription', self.parse_transcription, meta={'items': items})

    def parse_transcription(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['Transcription_price'] = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()
        yield items
```